# "update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/unicorn_app: file does not exist" in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, nginx, unicorn

I am trying configure unicorn + nginx in my ubunton 10.04 in linode for deploy my rails app and when I execute the command:

```
sudo update-rc.d unicorn_app defaults
```

I get the next error:

```
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/unicorn_app: file does not exist
```

However I can see the `unicorn_app` file in `init.d` folder. The `unicorn_app` file color is red with background grey in ubuntu terminal.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the "red" colour in LS means that unicorn_app is a broken symbolic link. Please try `ls -l /etc/init.d/unicorn_app`, see if the file it points to exist or not.

In addition, you may run `file /etc/init.d/unicorn_app` to see if it is a broken symbolic link or not.

Comment: Is there another way to fix this issue? I successfully ran these commands and am still having the same problem. `deploy@server:~$ sudo update-rc.d unicorn_testapp defaults`  
 update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/unicorn_testapp: file does not exist 
`deploy@server:~$ ls -l /etc/init.d/unicorn_testapp` 
total 4, -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1682 Jun 26 23:19 unicorn_init.sh    
`deploy@server:~$ file /etc/init.d/unicorn_testapp`  
/etc/init.d/unicorn_testapp: directory    
`deploy@server:~$ sudo update-rc.d unicorn_testapp defaults`   
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/unicorn_testapp: file does not exist

Comment: @Nickdb93 You successfully ran these commands but they did not complete successfully.

Comment: Yes, my apologies about the confusing wording. I did NOT successfully run these commands. I believe I know the root of my issue. Check this out `root@server:~# sudo update-rc.d unicorn_qwesteraconnect/unicorn_init.sh defaults` 
 Adding system startup for `/etc/init.d/unicorn_qwesteraconnect/unicorn_init.sh` ...
   `/etc/rc0.d/K20unicorn_qwesteraconnect/unicorn_init.sh` -> `../init.d/unicorn_qwesteraconnect/unicorn_init.sh`
update-rc.d: symlink: `No such file or directory`   The problem was that I specified my directory, but not the init file itself. However, I'm running into a different issue.

Comment: When trying to run `cap production deploy` the deploy fails and says `SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@162.212.130.214: /etc/init.d/unicorn_qwesteraconnect/restart exit status: 126
/etc/init.d/unicorn_qwesteraconnect/restart stdout: Nothing written
/etc/init.d/unicorn_qwesteraconnect/restart stderr: /usr/bin/env: /etc/init.d/unicorn_qwesteraconnect/restart:` I believe this is because it's looking for a separate FILE for each command, when all of my commands are in the same file. I'm not sure what to do about this, however.

Comment: @Nickdb93 Maybe, it is more appropriate for a separate question. Others maybe able to help you as well.

Comment: @RaymondTau I think you're definitely right. I'm taking a break from deployment for now though and getting back to development. When I get some more patience I'll go ahead and post a question for this. Thank you for the advice.